# Spring+Hibernate: Inserting mutliple records and @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I have an application built on Spring+Hibernate. I'm trying to insert data into the database from a list of entries in a file. The basic idea is to insert all the records which have valid data and log an error report for all the entries that haven't been inserted.

A service class, which is @Transactional, calls another service class to read the file and insert into the DB. At moment, I insert the records one after the other. Maybe I'll change this to Batch Processing. The insertion is executed in a try catch block.

The pseudo-code:

```
@Transactional
class MainService {     
     public void insertFromFile(File inputFile) {
          subServuce(toIterator(inputFile)); // toIterator(..) is just for understanding. 
     } 
}

class SubService {
    public void insert(Iterator input) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
             try {
                 DBService.save(input.next());
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // Log the error and continue with next records
             }
        }
    }
}

@Transactional
class DBService {
     public void save(Data input) {
          generalDao.save(input);
     }
}
```

Tried:

```
class SubService {
    public void insert(Iterator input) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
             try {
                 save(input.next());
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // Log the error and continue with next records
             }
        }
    }

    // @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save(Data input) {
        DBService.save(input);
    }
}
```

Even though the exception is handled, the entire transaction is being rolled back and I get this error `Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`

I tried specifying `@Transactional(noRollBack = Exception.class)` on `SubService.insert(..)`, that did not work.

The following are my questions:

1. How do I tell Spring not to roll back and continue with the other records.
2. Is it good practice to not to roll back while inserting multiple records? Doesn't this defy the Atomicity rule?
3. In batch processing, how is this handled? If an error occurs are all inserted or none?

   Solution:

With the help of @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu's answer, was able to solve this.

Created a layer between SubService and DBService with the Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. The issue was that even though SubService.save(..) is annotated with @Transactional, as it belongs to the same Bean, the proxy will not treat it as a different session.

```
SubServiceDao {
    // @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(Data input) {
        DBService.save(input);
    }
}

class SubService {
    public void insert(Iterator input) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
             try {
                 SubServiceDao.save(input.next());
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // Log the error and continue with next records
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: < I have the same requirement(to insert list of entity). I want to rollback for all the exceptions except DuplicateKey related exceptions. Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137/problem-in-handling-unit-of-work-using-hibernate-jpa?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you are catching the exception the Spring would still be able to detect that something has gone wrong with `entityManager`and in such cases it marks the transaction as rollback only.

This is because the `entityManager` Spring injects is a proxy that intercepts all the calls before delegating to real `entityManager` and gets it know that exception has been thrown by the real `entityManager` even if you catch it.

One option I see is you can start a new transaction on `DBService.save(...)` method  `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. That way if any exception occurs due to invalid data it effects insertion of only that row and remaining will still continue.

Comment: Hey! DBService itself is annotated with @Transactional. I updated my question showing the DBService class. Anyway, I moved the part which calls DBService to another method and marked it as Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW/NOT_SUPPORTED. None worked.

Comment: Did you try by adding `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` on  the `generalDao.save(input)` method in the dao class. Because you should be adding this annotation on the method that is interacting with `entityManager`. I believe `generalDao.save(input)` is the one that interacts with the entitymanager. Remaining others can run in same transaction.

Comment: generalDao here is https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/ and I cannot change it's implementation for my specific purpose. So there is nothing much I can do here.

Comment: Got it. Although you have annotated `save(input)` method in `SubService` class with `REQUIRES_NEW`, the problem I see is, you are invoking this `save` method directly in the while loop. If we call a method directly it won't be Spring AOP proxied (no new transaction) and so it would be running in the same transaction as that of the caller. As a quick workaround can you call save method using - `((SubService) AopContext.currentProxy()).save(input)` or better moving the `save(input)` method into new bean and calling it using this new bean.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The initial answer which you gave helped me in solving the problem. I added another DAO between SubService and DBService and moved the persist method to that class. I updated my answer with solution.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, I want to insert List of Customers and while inserting if we get Duplicate key errors I want to igonore and insert others, if there are any other errors I want to roll back all Customers. Can you please advice he to achieve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137/problem-in-handling-unit-of-work-using-hibernate-jpa

Answer (score 0):

From the [Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) javadoc:

> If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
>   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
>   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

So, the entire transaction is rolled back and nothing remains inserted.

Do do validation (and necessary locking if needed) before inserting and retry the entire transaction in case of failure.